# react-native executing unsuccessful

Tags: android, react-native

[image: React Native project runtime ****]

Hello,I'm new in React-native I got this from yesterday when I going to execute my react-native project. I clean cache , gradle clean, npm restart, Pc restart, react-native start not getting anything how I have to solve ? Your help will be highly appreciatable

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show any error. What is the error you faced

Comment: Sometimes It takes some time to load js files during debugging. Better you can create a release apk and test. This will reduce the loading time.

Comment: I have not faced any error

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with watchman can you please check weather watchman is installed properly.